# Postgresql, sorting selected data(timestamp)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I've done a select from two tables:

```
select a.frequency+b.lastrun
from a, b where a.id = b.a_id;
```

And I get the output:

```
          ?column?
----------------------------
 2015-01-03 09:02:10.300201
 2015-01-09 09:02:10.300201
 2015-01-03 09:02:10.300201
 2015-01-02 21:02:10.300201
 2015-01-02 15:02:10.300201
 2015-01-09 09:02:10.300201
 2015-02-01 09:02:10.300201
 2015-01-03 09:02:10.300201
 2015-01-02 10:02:10.300201
 2015-01-03 09:02:10.300201
```

How do I sort this data by decrement ?

Comment: I want it to be sorted by timestamp from the oldest to newest

Comment: What's wrong with using `order by`?

Comment: But how do I use this here ?

Comment: The question is how do I order this column if it is named "?column?"

Comment: Oh, sry I got to the answer, ill just use select ... as ... structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply supply the column number for the `order by` clause:

```
select a.frequency+b.lastrun
from a, b 
where a.id = b.a_id
order by 1;
```

Or use an alias

```
select a.frequency+b.lastrun as ts
from a, b 
where a.id = b.a_id
order by ts;
```

This is well documented in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-order.html

---

You should also get used to explicit joins rather than the old-style implicit joins.

```
select a.frequency+b.lastrun
from a
  join b on a.id = b.a_id
order by 1;
```

Comment: ASC or DESC make the ORDER BY even more readable, but ASC is the default anyway.